# C/C++ Search for a folder from a root location and return absolute path

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to make a program which copies a folder from one location to another, but without knowing the exact path of source folder, only a root location.

I've managed to find a cmd command (***xcopy*** 'sourcePath' E:\Destination\Target /E /I /H) but the problem is that sourcePath is not always the same

e.g.

Root location: **D:\Root**

Destination location: **E:\Destination**

In root location I want to search for a folder named **Target** which can be anywhere in a subdirectory (e.g. **D:\Root\Dir1\Subdir1\Target** or **D:\Root\Dir2\Subdir2\SSubdir2\Target** or ...)

So I don't know the exact number of subdirectories in root location and I'm wondering if there is a method which can search for that specific folder starting from root location and if it finds it, to return the absolute path of it.

Comment: C or C++? Which is the actual language you're using?

Comment: It doesn't really matter because I want to make a DLL. However, I think that it will be better if it can be done in C.

Comment: I can only think of the obvious way: search recursively for the target, then 'assemble' the absolute path.

Comment: It absolutely does matter.

Comment: Agree. C++ has `<filesystem>` library, C does not.

Comment: If so, then C++.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you need to find a directory called "Target", and then copy it.

In order to implement these 2 steps, I invite you to check those 2 stackoverflow questions, which in my opinion contain the information you need :

[recursive file search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978644/recursive-file-search)

[how to copy folder from one path to another in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234562/how-to-copy-folder-from-one-path-to-another-in-c)
Best regards